# Prove a relation is primitive recursive, x is prime?

Tags: logic, computability, recursion

Is $\{x \in \mathbb{N}| \mbox{ x is prime}\}$ primitive recursive?

Hello,

$x \in \{x \in \mathbb{N}| \mbox{ x is prime}\} $ if and only if $ \forall y : y \le x \Rightarrow (y=1 \vee y=x \vee \neg (y|x))$

I already know that the union, =, 'dividisble by' is primitive recursive. Now my problem is $\forall y ..$.
We already discuss in the lecture that $R=\{(\overline{x},z): \mbox{for all } y<z: (\overline{x},y) \in P\}$ primitive recursive if $P \in \mathbb{N}^n$ is primitive recursive. But the exercise is of an other structure.

Comment: Your $P$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is it not? With $n=1$, so the situation is the question is, are the primes primitive recursive?

Comment: Sry, i don´t see that it has with n=1 the same structure..$R=\{(z): \mbox{ for all } y<z: y \in P\}$ but P also depends on z when i defined it like above.

Comment: What is a primitive recursive set? I was reading up on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_arithmetic), but the first one only defines functions, and the second one doesn't seem to talk about sets at all.

Comment: We define primitive recursive functions like in the first article. A set ist primitive recursice if and only if it´s characteristic function is primitive recursive. $R \in \mathbb{N}^l, K_R (\overline{x})= 1 \mbox{ if }\overline{x} \not\in R, K_r(\overline{x})=0 \mbox{ if } \overline{x} \in R $. With $\overline{x}$ i mean the l-tuple.

Comment: From the first link (wikipedia article): nth prime [is] primitive recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the set of prime numbers is primitive recursive. As you wrote, a number $z$ is prime if and only if there is no $y <z$ with $1 < y$ such that $y$ divides $z$. The set 
$$\{(y,z) : 1 < y < z \text{ and } y \text{ divides } z\}$$
is primitive recursive, and the set of non-primes is obtained from that set by a bounded quantification. The set of primes is then the complement of the set of non-primes; sometimes a special case is needed to ensure that $1$ is not called prime. So you have all the parts, and only need to assemble them.

Comment: But how that follows form the fact that $R=\{(\overline{x},z): \mbox{for all } y<z: (\overline{x},y) \in P\}$ primitive recursive if $P \in \mathbb{N}^n$ is primitive recursive? Hear is a bounded quantification but it has a other form than i need hear!

Comment: The proof that the primitive recursive relations are closed under bounded quantification is in many textbooks; it is a standard result.

Comment: But my question is if this result follow from the result above that we proof in the lecture! Is this a conclusion of it with composition?